# Suddenly Getting and Error When Deploying Dart App to GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, dart

I deployed twice today to different version (web3, and serverclient) and then suddenly I keep getting this error:

```
Could not start serving the given version.

DEBUG: Received error code [1] while running: [appcfg.py --application=arista-de
v --called_by_gcloud --noisy --oauth2 --oauth2_credential_file=C:\Users\Cristian
 Garcia\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\legacy_credentials\cgarcia.e88@gmail.com\singlest
ore.json --skip_sdk_update_check --version=clientserver --module=default update
C:\Users\Cristian Garcia\Documents\Dart\cloudsamples\clientserver\appengine_gene
rated_None_default_clientserver.yaml]

DEBUG: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 928, in Run
    result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\calliope\exceptions.py", line 78, in TryFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\ap
pengine\app_commands\deploy.py", line 154, in Run
    self.__Run(args, project, deployables)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\ap
pengine\app_commands\deploy.py", line 208, in __Run
    runner.Run('update', appyaml, module=module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\./lib\googlecl
oudsdk\appengine\lib\appengine_adapter.py", line 294, in Run
    raise AppcfgExecutionError(error_code, argv)
ToolException: Command failed with error code [1]
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1]
```

Now I can't deploy any Dart project to any of the old versions or even create new versions! (I don't know I having multiple version with different projects is a good thing, but I am just testing). I am totally stuck!!!

**EDIT**

This probably was a bug. Fixed itself after a couple of hours.

Comment: It should be fine to deploy up to 10 (as far as I know) versions and it shouldn't matter how much the versions differ. I think this is just a bug but I'm not sure where the the issue should be created (Dart issue tracker or gcloud issue tracker).

Comment: What do you mean by "deploy Dart application into GAE"? Currently Dart application can not be run on GAE, only using ManagedVMs ( https://www.dartlang.org/cloud/ ). May be you mean that you deploy compiled to JavaScript client-side application? In this case it depends on which GAE runtime you use (PHP,Java, Python or Go)

Comment: I seem to have run into this now. Very annoying