# Can no longer deploy Dart app to appengine - "Could not start serving the given version"

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, managed-vm

I can no longer deploy my app to appengine. I've tried several times today and yesterday. It seems to deploy OK but then can't start it.

Seems to be the same as [Suddenly Getting and Error When Deploying Dart App to GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095550/suddenly-getting-and-error-when-deploying-dart-app-to-gae)

I'm on docker 1.5. Latest dart, updated gcloud etc.
The following is parts of the output of running

```
gcloud --verbosity debug preview app deploy ../../app.yaml
```

Let me know if you need more of this output

```
DEBUG: Running gcloud.preview.app.deploy with Namespace(cmd_func=<bound method Command.Run of <googlecloudsdk.calliope.backend.Command object at 0x10a322110>>, command_path=['gcloud', 'preview', 'app', 'deploy'], compile_encoding='UTF-8', delete_jsps=False, deployables=['../../app.yaml'], do_jar_classes=False, do_jar_splitting=False, env_vars=None, force=False, format=None, h=None, help=None, http_timeout=None, jar_jsps=True, jar_splitting_exclude_suffixes='', log_http=None, markdown=None, no_symlinks=False, project=None, quiet=None, remote=False, retain_upload_dir=False, server=None, set_default=False, trace_token=None, user_output_enabled=None, verbosity='debug', version=None).

....

DEBUG: Running [appcfg.py] with: appcfg.py --application=gitbacklog --called_by_gcloud --noisy --oauth2 --oauth2_credential_file=/Users/blah/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/xxxxxxx@gmail.com/singlestore.json --skip_sdk_update_check --version=0-10-0-1-1428041261626 prepare_vm_runtime

....

INFO: Image gitbacklog.default.0-10-0-1-1428041261626 built, id = c2956e16b8ea
DEBUG: Detected docker environment variables: DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376, DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/blah/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm, DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 192.168.59.103
DEBUG: "GET /v1.10/_ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2
DEBUG: Configured access to gcr.io.
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/c2956e16b8ea/tag?repo=gcr.io%2F_m_gitbacklog%2Fgitbacklog.default.0-10-0-1-1428041261626&force=1 HTTP/1.1" 201 0
Pushing image to Google Container Registry...
INFO: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): gcr.io
DEBUG: "GET /v1/_ping HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/gcr.io/_m_gitbacklog/gitbacklog.default.0-10-0-1-1428041261626/push HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Sending image list

....

Image successfully pushed===================================>] 1.024 kB/1.024 kB 5s
Pushing tag for rev [c2956e16b8ea] on {https://gcr.io/v1/repositories/_m_gitbacklog/gitbacklog.default.0-10-0-1-1428041261626/tags/latest}
DEBUG: Running [appcfg.py] with: appcfg.py --application=gitbacklog --called_by_gcloud --noisy --oauth2 --oauth2_credential_file=/Users/blah/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/xxxxxx@gmail.com/singlestore.json --skip_sdk_update_check --version=0-10-0-1-1428041261626 --module=default update /Users/blah/dart/backlogio/appengine_generated_None_default_0-10-0-1-1428041261626.yaml
05:21 PM Host: appengine.google.com
05:21 PM Application: gitbacklog (was: None); version: 0-10-0-1-1428041261626
INFO: Reading app configuration.
05:21 PM 
Starting update of app: gitbacklog, version: 0-10-0-1-1428041261626

....

INFO: Send: /api/appversion/create, params={'version': '0-10-0-1-1428041261626', 'app_id': 'gitbacklog', 'module': 'default'}
DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=gitbacklog&module=default&version=0-10-0-1-1428041261626 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '620', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=api_version: '1'

....

05:21 PM WARNING: Performance settings included in this update are being ignored because your application is not using the Modules feature. See the Modules documentation for more information. Python: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/ Java: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/ Go: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/modules/ PHP: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/.
05:21 PM Cloning 1 application file.
INFO: Send: /api/appversion/clonefiles, params={'version': '0-10-0-1-1428041261626', 'app_id': 'gitbacklog', 'module': 'default'}
INFO: Adding file app.yaml (497 bytes, type=application/octet-stream) to batch.
INFO: Uploading batch of 1 files to /api/appversion/addfiles with boundary="boundary".
INFO: Send: /api/appversion/addfiles, params={'version': '0-10-0-1-1428041261626', 'app_id': 'gitbacklog', 'module': 'default'}

....

05:21 PM Starting deployment.
INFO: Send: /api/appversion/deploy, params={'version': '0-10-0-1-1428041261626', 'app_id': 'gitbacklog', 'module': 'default'}
DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?app_id=gitbacklog&module=default&version=0-10-0-1-1428041261626 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=
05:21 PM Checking if deployment succeeded.
INFO: Send: /api/appversion/isready, params={'version': '0-10-0-1-1428041261626', 'app_id': 'gitbacklog', 'module': 'default'}
DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/isready?app_id=gitbacklog&module=default&version=0-10-0-1-1428041261626 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=
05:21 PM Deployment successful.
INFO: Send: /api/appversion/startserving, params={'willcheckserving': '1', 'version': '0-10-0-1-1428041261626', 'app_id': 'gitbacklog', 'module': 'default'}
DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/startserving?app_id=gitbacklog&module=default&version=0-10-0-1-1428041261626&willcheckserving=1 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=
05:21 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.
INFO: Send: /api/appversion/isserving, params={'new_serving_resp': '1', 'version': '0-10-0-1-1428041261626', 'app_id': 'gitbacklog', 'module': 'default'}
DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/isserving?app_id=gitbacklog&module=default&new_serving_resp=1&version=0-10-0-1-1428041261626 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=
05:21 PM Will check again in 5 seconds.
05:21 PM Checking if updated app version is serving.

....

05:28 PM Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Deployed Version: 0-10-0-1-1428041261626.383337128523335799
ERROR: Not enough VMs ready (0/1 ready, 1 still deploying). Deployed Version: 0-10-0-1-1428041261626.383337128523335799
05:28 PM Rolling back the update.  This can sometimes take a while since a VM version is being rolled back.
INFO: Send: /api/appversion/rollback, params={'version': '0-10-0-1-1428041261626', 'app_id': 'gitbacklog', 'module': 'default'}
DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/rollback?app_id=gitbacklog&force_rollback=0&module=default&version=0-10-0-1-1428041261626 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '0', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=
INFO: Send: /api/logclientdeploy, params={'version': '0-10-0-1-1428041261626', 'app_id': 'gitbacklog', 'module': 'default'}
DEBUG: _Authenticate configuring auth; needs_auth=False
DEBUG: Sending request to https://appengine.google.com/api/logclientdeploy?app_id=gitbacklog&module=default&version=0-10-0-1-1428041261626 headers={'X-appcfg-api-version': '1', 'content-length': '12795', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} body=end_time_usec: 1428042523836176
requests:
- end_time_usec: 1428042081461982
  path: /api/appversion/getresourcelimits
  request_size_bytes: 0
  response_code: 200
  start_time_usec: 1428042080778570

....

- end_time_usec: 1427796937265279
  path: /api/appversion/rollback
  request_size_bytes: 0
  response_code: 200
  start_time_usec: 1427796936628062
runtime: vm
sdk_version: 1.9.18
start_time_usec: 1427796493970315
success: false

Could not start serving the given version.
DEBUG: Received error code [1] while running: [appcfg.py --    application=gitbacklog --called_by_gcloud --noisy --oauth2 --oauth2_credential_file=/Users/blah/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/xxxxxxx@gmail.com/singlestore.json --skip_sdk_update_check --version=0-10-0-1-1427796457623 --module=default update /Users/blah/dart/backlogio/appengine_generated_None_default_0-10-0-1-1427796457623.yaml]
DEBUG: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/blah/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 559, in Execute
result = args.cmd_func(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/blah/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 1020, in Run
result = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/blah/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/exceptions.py", line 86, in TryFunc
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/blah/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/deploy.py", line 160, in Run
self.__Run(args, project, deployables)
  File "/Users/blah/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/app_commands/deploy.py", line 210, in __Run
runner.Run('update', appyaml, module=module)
  File "/Users/blah/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/appengine/lib/appengine_adapter.py", line 317, in Run
raise AppcfgExecutionError(error_code, argv)
ToolException: Command failed with error code [1]
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1]
{bucket: vm-containers.gitbacklog.appspot.com, path: /containers}
```

Comment: Have you tried if `--verbosity debug` provides more details, or to specify a version when you deploy or use `--force`, and/or maybe `--set-default`?

Comment: Yes I always run with `--verbosity debug`. I don't want to use `--set-default` as I don't want to make this the default yet. I haven't tried `--force` or specifying a version on the command line as my grinder scripts update the version in app.yaml with a timestamp suffix to make sure it's unique. 
The version was successfully created according to the appengine console (at https://0-10-0-1-1427796457623-dot-gitbacklog.appspot.com/). It just isn't accessible. But no info about why

Comment: Looks similar to https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/m/#!topic/cloud/ubNj2Btl7lk Did you check the quota limits?

Comment: All my quotas look fine. So doubt it relates to that. 
Unfortunately, I had the bad idea of restarting my live version. Despite having successfully run for a week or so, this instance does not start either. So I now have A TOTAL SITE OUTAGE.
I suspect the problem lies with the new "Haswell" servers that google cloud is rolling out. Before restarting this instance was running on the "Intel Sandy Bridge" servers. When it tried to start it was on a new "Haswell" server. I wonder if there is a problem running dart vm's on this new infrastructure.